# sort struct array alphabetically

Tags: sorting

In my struct ,i'm trying to sort items alphabetically by user's last name

This is a part of my code :

```
struct users {
char uname[30];
char lname[30];
char mellicode[30];
int userid;

};
struct users libuser[1000];


void adduser(int id){
char temp[30];
cout<<"Enter Username :\n";
cin>>temp;
strcpy(libuser[id].uname,temp);
cout<<"Enter Lastname :\n";
cin>>temp;
strcpy(libuser[id].lname,temp);
cout<<"Enter Mellicode :\n";
cin>>temp;
strcpy(libuser[id].mellicode,temp);
libuser[id].userid = id;
 }



void showuser(int id){
cout<<"\nUsername :"<<libuser[id].uname<<"\nLast name :"<<libuser[id].lname<<"\nMelli code :"<<libuser[id].mellicode<<"\nUser ID :"<<libuser[id].userid<<"\n";
```

}

```
void swapuser(int id,int id2){
char temp[30];
int itemp=id;

    strcpy(temp,libuser[id].uname);
    strcpy(libuser[id].uname,libuser[id2].uname);
    strcpy(libuser[id2].uname,temp);

    strcpy(temp,libuser[id].lname);
    strcpy(libuser[id].lname,libuser[id2].lname);
    strcpy(libuser[id2].lname,temp);

    strcpy(temp,libuser[id].mellicode);
    strcpy(libuser[id].mellicode,libuser[id2].mellicode);
    strcpy(libuser[id2].mellicode,temp);

    id=id2;
    id2=itemp;
}
```

and here i tried to sort them :

```
for (int h=0;h<1000;h++)
{
    for(int l=0; l<1000; l++)
    {
        if(libuser[l].userid!=0)
        if(strcmp(libuser[l].lname,libuser[l+1].lname)>0)   
        { 
            swapuser(l,l+1);
        }

    }
}


for (int i=0;i<1000;i++)
    if(libuser[i].userid!=0)
    showuser(i);

system("pause");
```

i have two problems :

1.the sorting part doesn't work well.

2.In user's array there are several empty items ,like these :

libuser[0].lname = asdf

libuser[1].lname =

libuser[2].lname =

libuser[3].lname = zxcdg

libuser[4].lname = gsagg

libuser[5].lname = gasgh

libuser[6].lname =

libuser[7].lname = asggg

libuser[8].lname =

libuser[9].lname =

libuser[10].lname =

...

if they are empty ,their libuser[X].userid became 0 ,so i can find empy items but i have no idea about sorting them !

Comment: Good news: you can use a standard library algorithm, std::sort. You will have to define a comparison function. Search around, as there are many questions about custom comparisons. Also, if this is C++, you should tag it as such.

Comment: std::sort is ok for simple stuff but not as efficient as qsort for large amounts of data.  It executes the copy constructor for two objects in every comparison.  It is elegant but unfortunately elegance doesn't make it faster.

Answer (score 0):

first: change

```
for(int l=0; l<1000; l++)
```

to

```
for(int l=0; l<998; l++)
```

because:

```
swapuser(l,l+1); //l+1 should <= 999
```

second: you should exchange userid but not id in `swapuser`.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you get rid of all the ones where userid = 0 first?

Once you've done that, ff you are using a selection sort, then the code should read something like

```
for (int h=0;h<999;h++)
{
    int lowest = h;
    for(int l=h + 1; l<1000; l++)
    {
        if(strcmp(libuser[lowest].lname,libuser[l].lname)>0)   
            lowest = l;
    }
    if (lowest != h)
        swapuser(h,lowest);
}
```

For swapping - there is a feature known as structure copy.  It is not new: it has been around since C89 or possibly even earlier.

```
void swapuser(int hi, int lo)
{
    struct users temp;
    temp = libuser[hi];
    libuser[hi] = libuser[lo];
    libuser[lo] = temp;
}
```

Comment: Just noticed you're using C++.  You can drop the struct.